# How would someone break into a vault in a pocket dimension?

Tags: magic, dimensions, money

In my fantasy world, most very rich people hide their wealth in a pocket dimension. Now, normally there are two ways to get into a pocket dimension: a spell that requires a tuning fork with a VERY specific frequency of resonation (Yes, D&D rules), and a portal.

The owners of the vault, however, ensure that the only way to access the vault is via tuning fork, and turning off portals. Usually, they hire a wizard to summon the fork and cast the spell whenever they want to access the vault (a mere pittance for them), then they melt the tuning fork.

If someone was going to steal from one of these rich people, what kind of issues might happen and how would the wealthy person further prevent people from stealing from them?

Comment: This sounds a bit like a "_how should I write my story_" sort of question, which is considered to be off-topic here. Sounds like this is going to be an elaborate heist involving various bits of sleight of hand and cat burglary to obtain a suitable copy of the tuning fork, then probably some shenanigans with an untrustworthy or under-skilled mage, etc etc. Hijinks ensue. Probably not quite worldbuilding, though.

Comment: I'd love it if you could edit your question to make it more about "rules of your world" and less about "how can a burglar do her job?"

Comment: Hopefully this is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.**Mockingbird.**

A trained mockingbird unobtrusively listens as the fork is summoned and played.  On returning to its handlers the mockingbird whistles the pitch.  When a fork with that pitch opens the vault, the mockingbird is rewarded with many grubs.

2. **Brute force.**

A thick tuning fork is made with a low frequency and checked to see if a picked dimension vault corresponds.  If not, the fork is very lightly sanded to raise the frequency and tried again.  Repeat.

Eventually the fork will open someplace.  Then not.  Eventually again the fork will open someplace else.  It might be possible to induce (inductive reasoning!) a pattern in how used frequencies are spaced which will speed the sequence of raising the fork frequency.

Eventually you will find the pocket dimension with the vault you are after.  You might find other things.  Be careful.  Record all successful frequencies.  They might be useful later.

3. **Pittance x 10**

Hire the wizard.  Tell him your rich buddy referred you.  Have him make a pocket dimension opened by a fork.  Thank him and stow your stuff in there.  Then have your confederates hire him for the same thing.  And again.  And again.  Pay attention to the frequencies he uses.  This boring work pays the bills and he is probably riffing on the same method over and over.  Once you figure out his pattern in making pocket dimensions, deduce what the frequencies are for other dimensions he has made.

4. **Pittance <sup>2</sup>**

Hire that wizard.  Pay him a lot more than the other folks paid.  Make sure he understands that after this job he will need to lay low for a good while.

I like the caper where there are different groups using each of these methods at the same time.

Comment: 1. I am assuming this mockingbird would be magical in a way to mimic a magical tune of this device. Im assuming a wizard able to create dimensions could detect a magical creature listening in. 
2. This sounds basically how people get into garages and cars now. Get a device that transmits radio frequencies similar to how those devices transmit and just bombard a parking lot until something opens. Not very targeted, but I think this is the best. 
3. this could get very costly, paying a guy to basically create a dimension and hope it works
4. a wizard doesnt survive long by betraying clients

Comment: I should clarify. I think your #2 is the most realistic for a burglarer to use. Although, a skilled and well connected thief specifically targeting a person may employ special tactics, such as magical beasts

Answer (score 0):

With his magic  Pocket dimension opener obviously?  Seriously though if the rich hide things in pockets dimensions then they have a way of opening them so they can put more stuff in or take stuff out. i.e this magical tuning fork.  So then all you have to do is replicate that just like you  Would  Replicate a key or a key card to break into a house.  If  Making a identical copy of the key is impossible is impossible and perhaps a spell that's designed the function as a copy would work.